# Variable expression contains another variable

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to put some variable inside Variable Expression of another variable.
For example:

`$V{sum} = $F{quantity} * ${price}`, where sum is simple variable without any calculation
`$V{total} = $F{disb} * $V{price}`, where total has 'Sum' calculation type.

As a result I receive the wrong amount.

But If I use:

```
$V{total} = $F{disb} * $F{quantity} * ${price}
```

the amount is valid.

Is there any reason that variable inside variable expression gives wrong value? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are outputting the $V{total} of your first example in a textfield, then you will need to make sure the **Evaluation Time** is set correctly per your report. Most likely you will want to set the field evaluation time to "Report".

The evaluation time determines when dynamically calculated variables are actually *processed* during the report's generation life-cycle.

Comment: Do you mean Increment type? I can't find Evaluation time.. Tried to set it to Report. With one example it really works. But when I try to put hierarchial structure such as var->var->var it still gives wrong value. Maybe I should to play with that option. Thanks

Comment: I assume you are outputting your calculation in a TextField.  Text fields have an "Evaluation Time" property that can be set to Now, Report, Page, Column, Group, Band, or Auto.